# Using BevelBitmapEffect on WPF Path

Tags: wpf, bitmapeffect

I am trying to add a BevelBitmapEffect on my existing Path object:

[image]

```
<Path x:Name="A037" Width="174.024" Height="20.0028" Canvas.Left="1717.02" 
    Canvas.Top="1157.83" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.00028" 
    StrokeLineJoin="Round" Stroke="#FF000000" Fill="#DC4C46" 
    Data="F1 M 1721.02,1158.83L 1718.02,1176.83L 1888.04,1176.83L 1890.04,1158.83L 1721.02,1158.83 Z ">
    <Path.BitmapEffect>
        <BevelBitmapEffect BevelWidth="3"/>
    </Path.BitmapEffect>
</Path>
```

but to no avail.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `BitmapEffect` is obsolete and it no longer takes any effect

Comment: @Flithor Even if I downgrade the target .NET framework?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something?

`BitmapEffects` such as the `BevelBitmapEffect` are obsolete since .NET Framework 4. Your sample should work as expected only if you target .NET Framework 3.0 or 3.5.

The WPF4+ alternative to using the `BevelBitmapEffect` class would be to create a custom class that inherits from `Effect`. I am afraid there are no built-in types that gives you a corresponding bevel effect out of the box.